# Javascript function programming — receiving elaborate parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameter-passing

I'm writing a Javascript function that would manipulate an array written on-the-fly and sent as a parameter.

The function is written as follows:

```
function returnJourney(animation,clean){
    var properties = {};
    // loads of other inane stuff
    for(i in animation[0]) properties[animation[0][i]] = animation[0].i;
    // heaps more inane stuff
}
```

The animation in question is a set of parameters for a jQuery animation. Typically it takes the format of `({key:value,key:value},speedAsInteger,modifierAsString)`.

So to kick off initial debugging I call it with:

`returnJouney(({'foo':'bar'},3000),1);`

And straight off the bat things are way off. As far as I see it this would have returnJourney acknowledge `clean === 1`, and `animation` being an array with an object as its first child and the number 3000 as its second.

Firebug tells me `animation` evaluates as the number 3000. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
properties[animation[0][i]] = animation[0].i;
```

should be

```
properties[animation[0][i]] = animation[0][i];
```

`.i` is the property literally called `'i'`. As that (probably) doesn't exist, you'll be assigning `undefined` to each property.

```
returnJouney(({'foo':'bar'},3000),1);
```

also makes little sense — do you mean an array?:

```
returnJourney([{'foo':'bar'},3000],1);
```

(there is no ‘tuple’ type in JavaScript.)

Also, use `var i in` rather than the (typo) `in in`. Forgetting `var` gives you an accidental global, with potentially annoying-to-debug side-effects.

Comment: Thanks Bob, just needed an array syntax refresher :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no tuple type in JavaScript. All you have is either object `{}` or array `[]`. Both of them can understand any mixture of types. So you can either pass your animation parameter as array (`[{'foo':'bar'},3000]`), which looks like exactly what you wanted.
Or, as it usually done in JavaScript, use object instead:

```
returnJourney({props: {foo: "bar"}, speed: 3000}, 1);

function returnJourney(animation, clean) {
     var props = animation.props;
     var speed = animation.speed;
}
```

Note that object notation let you ignore things you don't want to pass and makes it very clear what value means what.

As for why your `animation` resolves as 3000, it is really simple, this is how `,` operator works. It returns the last thing in braces. So `(10, 20, 30)` would evaluate to `30`, so will `(f(1000), "hello", 30)`. Only last value matters, others just ignored (but run anyway, so any side effects will be there).

Answer (score 0):

It's treating `({'foo':'bar'},3000)` as an expression using the comma operator, which returns the right operand as its result. Perhaps you meant `[{'foo':'bar'},3000]`.